# Scala 2.8 and Map views

Tags: scala, scala-2.8, lazy-evaluation

In **2.7** I could do the following:

```
val lazyM: Map[_, _] = map.projection.mapElements(v => expCalc(v)) //MAP VIEW
```

I can't find a way of doing this in **2.8** and actually *ending up with a map*:

```
val m: Map[_, _] = map.view.map(kv => kv._1 -> expCalc(kv._2)).toMap //STRICT
```

This seems like a significant loss of functionality and therefore I assume it's hiding in the collection library somewhere. Anyone have any ideas?

**Edit** - *stupidly I assumed that mapValues was exactly the same as the old mapElements*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Somewhat surprisingly, `Map#mapValues` produces a (transformed) view:

```
scala> Map(1 -> 2, 3 -> 4, 5 -> 6)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map((1,2), (3,4), (5,6))

scala> res0.mapValues { v => println("computing from " + v); v + 1 }
computing from 2
computing from 4
computing from 6
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map((1,3), (3,5), (5,7))

scala> res1(1)
computing from 2
res2: Int = 3

scala> res1(5)
computing from 6
res3: Int = 7
```

Comment: This is not exactly "lazy" (zero or one evaluations per key with those evaluations delayed as long as possible), it's more like "dynamic" in that the function supplied in the call to `mapValues` is evaluated *every time a key in the resulting Map view is retrieved*.

Comment: Yes, it's what I meant though. I shouldn't have used the word lazy

Comment: I'd suggest saying "mapValues returns a view".